# How to convert MLKit Vision3DPoint to UV Coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, google-mlkit

#### Goal

- **Convert** MLKit **Vision3DPoint** **to** **UV Coordinates** or **AVFoundation Coordinates**

#### Detail

I try to use MLKit from Google by following [these steps](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/pose-detection/ios) to detect the human pose, but the result is in 3D space

#### Example of Landmark Position

```
Position:  x: 1175.290893554688, y: -3.273239135742188, z: 2.268885850906372
Position:  x: 1283.07568359375, y: 18.44030952453613, z: -266.7630615234375
Position:  x: 4367.9072265625, y: 687.6997680664062, z: -358.7154846191406
Position:  x: 3602.029052734375, y: 621.983642578125, z: -1123.94580078125
...
```

But the answer I want is **where is each point on the image (UV coordinates)**?

#### Expected result

[image]

```
// Example
UV:  u: 0.1, v: 0.2, Screen: x: 100, y: 200
...
```

#### Code

```swift
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    
    // Prepare Input
    let image = VisionImage(buffer: sampleBuffer)
    image.orientation = imageOrientation(deviceOrientation: UIDevice.current.orientation, cameraPosition: camera.position)
    
    // To detect objects asynchronously
    poseDetector.process(image) { [unowned self] (detectedPoses, error) in
        
        guard error == nil else { return }
        
        guard let detectedPoses = detectedPoses, !detectedPoses.isEmpty else { return }
        
        // Success. Get pose landmarks here.
        
        for pose in detectedPoses {
            let landmarks = pose.landmarks
            for landmark in landmarks {

                // This will return a 3D point
                // Example: x: 1175.290893554688, y: -3.273239135742188, z: 2.268885850906372
                let position = landmark.position

                // pointView.points needs 2D Point (UV Coordinate)
                // Example: x: 0.12, y: 0.78 (u, v)
                owner.pointView.points.append((CGPoint(x: position.x, y: position.y), UIColor.red))
            }
        }
        owner.pointView.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You should ignore the z-axis for 2-D image, and need to normalize the x-axis and y-axis point. To normalize these points, please look at **normalizedPoint** function in MLKit iOS sample app [https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/ios/quickstarts/vision/VisionExample/CameraViewController.swift](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/blob/master/ios/quickstarts/vision/VisionExample/CameraViewController.swift) I hope it help.

Comment: Right, as shown in ML Kit's doc (https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/pose-detection#z_coordinate) and quickstart app, the z coordinate is relative to the hip. It's not a true 3D value. The point that MLKit returns is already in the 2D image coordinate space. You just need to get x and y values from the returned MLKVision3DPoint, normalize them by the image width and height respectively, and then apply any transformations necessary to account for the orientation in the image when showing it on-screen. For your use case, as Ashish said, you can ignore the z coordinate.